# Access SAP R/3 data directly from VB.NET

Tags: .net, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-erp, sap-r3

We have an assignment to create some XML outputs from data in SAP R/3. We are using SAP .NET Connector, for doing this. The problem we are facing is that there are some fields which are not exposed by any standard BAPI. Unfortunately we cannot create customized BAPI on this particular system.

We are therefore restricted to whatever standard BAPI are available. I have seen on internet that tools like ERPConnect can provide access to tables directly using RFC. How can this be performed in VB, without purchasing any such tool, using or without using .NET Connector.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the function module RFC_READ_TABLE. Be sure to read the entire documentation - it has some limitations depending on the SAP R/3 release.

Answer (score 0):

You may access directly the database system which is connected to SAP and stores its data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE instead of RFC_READ_TABLE, if you cannot use other tools.

BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE resolves one field length issue for negative decimal values as seen in RFC_READ_TABLE. Basically, RFC_READ_TABLE does not handle the requirement for minus sign space and had to use asterisk instead when the value occupies the full length. BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE detects decimals type and pad it by 1.